# Your session crashed after using all available RAM in Google Collab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I have 6 big data tsv files which I am reading into dataframes within Google Collab. However, the files are too big and Google Colab cannot handle it.

```
#Crew data
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'16'}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('title.crew.tsv') 
df_crew = pd.read_csv('title.crew.tsv',header=None,sep='\t',dtype='unicode')

#Ratings data
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'15'}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('title.ratings.tsv') 
df_ratings = pd.read_csv('title.ratings.tsv',header=None,sep='\t',dtype='unicode')


#Episode data
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'14'}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('title.episode.tsv') 
df_episode = pd.read_csv('title.episode.tsv',header=None,sep='\t',dtype='unicode')

#Name Basics data
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'13'}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('name.basics.tsv') 
df_name = pd.read_csv('name.basics.tsv',header=None,sep='\t',dtype='unicode')

#Principals data
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'12'}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('title.pricipals.tsv') 
df_principals = pd.read_csv('title.pricipals.tsv',header=None,sep='\t',dtype='unicode')

#Title Basics data
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':'11'}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('title.basics.tsv') 
df_title = pd.read_csv('title.basics.tsv',header=None,sep='\t',dtype='unicode')
```

**Error: Your session crashed after using all available RAM. Runtime logs say this:**
[image]

How can Google Collab handle Ram better? The size of all my tsv files combined is 2,800 MB. Please advise!

Comment: Could you work with one file at a time, or does all the data from all the files really need to be in memory at the same time?

Comment: @NikolasStevenson-Molnar you mean put them all in seperate kernels instead in the same? I need all files to merge at some point but I can try seperate kernels.

Comment: I mean to read `df_crew`, do whatever you need to with it, free that memory with `del df_crew` or `df_crew = None`, then read `df_ratings`, work with that one... etc., etc., so that you only have one file's data in memory at once.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Google colab usually provides 12 GB's free ram but we can increase it with paying anything to google .

By writing just the three lines of code you can increase your Ram from 12GB to 25 GB

a = [ ]
while(1):
a.append('1')

Try this it might help.

Comment: Please provide a reference with an explanation of the workaround when answering

Comment: This no longer works when I try the instructions. I get a warning saying that I should upgrade to Google Collab pro after consuming all RAM available.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to only use data as you use it and delete it from memory. This can be done forcefully by causing the garbage collector to release (see thread here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python])[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python)

If you want to expand your RAM in Colab there used to be a hack where you intentionally caused it to run out of RAM and then it'll offer you a higher RAM runtime. This option can also be selected with Colab pro under Runtime -> Change Runtime Type. For $10 a month, Colab pro may very well be a good option for you.

I saw this hack [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/upgrade-your-memory-on-google-colab-for-free-1b8b18e8791d) but in short just append something to an array in a while loop until the RAM is depleted.

```
a = []
while 1:
    a.append("1")
```

Comment: The RAM expansion hack no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is working with any neural network model. The RAM offered in google-colab without google pro account is around 12GB. This could lead crashing of session due to low resources for some neural model. You can decrease the training and testing dataset by some amount and re-check the working of model. It might work well.

One can shuffle the dataset and use dataset less than the original dataset.

Comment: My dataset only have 3 columns and the maximum amount of rows before Colab crashed is before 40k row.